# jQuery overlapping issue with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The whole problem is that I have a header that is fixed and there's a div under it that I need to move accordingly. Though there is a problem if I click really fast like 3 or 4 times one of the animations messes up and I end up having the 'under' div inside the content. I use stop before animating and sliding. I tried using queue and such.. No avail.

```
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    $content = $header.next();
    $content.stop().slideToggle(500, function () {
    if(($('.lol').css('margin-top')) == '47px')
{
$(".under").stop().animate({'margin-top': "100px"}, 500)
}
else
{
$(".under").stop().animate({'margin-top': "47px"}, 500)
}
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zddzvxLy/8/

Here's jsfiddle to show the problem. Try clicking on the header a few times really fast and 'This one must be under" will appear inside CONTENT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have no item with the class `.lol` - change that to `.under`

Secondly, change your `stop()` calls to `stop(true, true)`

Thirdly, I would take your animation call for `.under` out of the `completed` function and call it in parallel with your first animation.

https://jsfiddle.net/zddzvxLy/10/

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to change everything from lol to under so the code would be more understandable and missed that one. Anyways, the stop(true, true) doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: In my example (revision 10 of your fiddle), the problem no longer persists.

Comment: Looks like the problem is solved. Thank you. I'll accept this answer as soon as it allows me. 
I checked the documentation of stop and this became clear now.
.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )

Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, check revision 11 for a demo that does not use a second animation. Im not sure why your header is `position:fixed;` - you may be better off not using that. You do not have to animation `under` if you don't. https://jsfiddle.net/zddzvxLy/11/

Comment: I have a small window with a scrollbar and I want the header to stay in position inside the window even if I scroll to the sides. Really complicated to explain the project is kinda huge and uses a BPM that doesn't allow me to solve this problem other way.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid calling `animate()` when the element is already being animated:

```
if ($('.content').is(':animated') === false)
{
    // animate
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```